# How to set ImageSource as Xamarin.Forms.Button?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying add a background image using the image property in button. The issue I'm facing is that i can't set StreamImageSource as button background. I encountered the error given below if I try to do so.

**The Code I use to set Image:**

```
            ImageSource iconsource =ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(ImgASBytes));
            Button Icon = new Button ();
            Icon.Image = iconsource ;
```

**The Error I encounter:**

Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource' to 'Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: The error message tells you that the button expects `FileImageSource`. Have you tried obeying?

Comment: Yes.. I did.. Image property only accepts file path in string.. And my question is how to cast **imagesource to fileimagesource**??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ImageSource.FromStream ()` returns a `StreamImageSource` (see [docs](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3AXamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromStream(System.Func%7BSystem.IO.Stream%7D))). `Button.Image` accepts only `FileImageSource` (see [docs](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3AXamarin.Forms.Button.Image)).

It means that what you're trying to achieve won't work, no matter how hard you try to cast one into the other.

`Button.Image` will accept images stored as resources in your platform projects, and loaded either with:

```cs
Icon.Image = ImageSource.FromFile ("foobar.png");
```

or

```cs
Icon.Image = "foobar.png";
```

Comment: ImageSource.FromFile also returns ImageSource instance. So Icon.Image=ImageSource.FromFile("foobar.png"); also results in a typecast error. Icon.Image=''foobar.png" is valid

Comment: @Sreeraj is right. We still haven't found the right way to do this.

Comment: @Sreeraj Also looking for this.

Comment: @stephane are you sure Button.Image accepts images only from platform resource folder. cant we take one from device internal storage ?

Comment: @Suchith at the time of the writing, yes, I was sure. This might have been fixed since, I don't recall.

Comment: I had the same issue @Sreeraj referenced. This was what worked for me:   Icon.Image = (FileImageSource)ImageSource.FromFile("foobar.png");

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is true that you can't **cast** `StreamImageSource` to `FileImageSource`, I think that the real question is about how to share images in a PCL and use them on a button, just like one would when creating an `Image` forms control.

The answer is to have a `Grid` which contains both a `Button` and an `Image` object, where the `Image` overlaps the `Button`.

For example, the C# code might look like this:

```
ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));

Button iconButton = new Button ();
iconButton.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
iconButton.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

var image = new Image();
image.Source = imageSource;
// So it doesn't eat up clicks that should go to the button:
image.InputTransparent = true;
// Give it a margin so it doesn't extend to the edge of the grid
image.Margin = new Thickness(10);

var grid = new Grid();
// If we don't set a width request, it may stretch horizontally in a stack
grid.WidthRequest = 48;
// Add the button first, so it is under the image...
grid.Children.Add(iconButton);
// ...then add the image
grid.Children.Add(image);
```

You may have to play with the sizes and thickness values but this should get you a clickable button with an icon.

Comment: Hello, maybe you found another way to use embedded resources more easily? Your answer is a working solution, but it seems to me that it's not the best practice to use this trick

Comment: This is a perfectly valid solution in my view and not a hack. `image.InputTransparent = true` makes the solution nice and clean, I think.

Answer (score 2):

As of Xamarin.Forms 3.4.0 you can now use ImageButton.  You can use embedded images by using an extension method [explained in this MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#using-xaml)

Answer (score 1):

Careful with upper- and lowercase in filenames.

I was wondering, why my button-images were shown properly on the simulator, but not on my iPhone.

On the device the filename must match exactly, the simulator doesn't care about upper- and lowercase in filenames.

Answer (score 0):

I use this and it works

```
var imageA = new Image();
imageA.Source=(FileImageSource)ImageSource.FromFile(allergeneLocation)};
```

or

```
var imageA = new Image()
{
BackgroundColor = Color.Teal,
Source = (FileImageSource)ImageSource.FromFile(allergeneLocation)},
};
```

Comment: This s setting the source of an Image, and not of a Button as the question is asking.

Comment: @kyle I was showing how he could deal with the
"Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource' to 'Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

by inspiring from the cast i performed in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried:

```
Button refreshBut = new Button
        {
            Image = (FileImageSource)
            (ImageSource.FromFile("refreshBut.png"))

        };
```

While it compiles I then get an unhandled null reference exception with the description: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I am not sure if this will help anyone else try to solve this but I am at the same wall.

Comment: Button refreshBut = new Button
        {
            Image = "refreshBut.png"

        };
You can just use it like this...

Comment: @FemilShajin whenever I do that I get a null exception because it cant find the resource.